# Launch collection view at index x without scrolling effect from index 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a news feed like page. The first page contains a list of post titles. Clicking on a particular post goes to a detail page. Now I want the detail page to be a collection view of all post details, in order to avoid constant back and forth between detail pages. The user must be able to scroll down to next post details rather than going back and selecting a new post title. When I click on post x, I want the detail page to directly show post detail x. I was able to achieve this by using scrolltoIndex:x. I would rather like to show the post detail x directly rather than going to post detail 0 and then quickly scrolling to x. While the user is directly taken to postDetail x, I want the above and below cells of the post detail to be filled, so the user can scroll smoothly to post detail of choice. Any suggestions here?

Here is what I am looking for. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHJJq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally cracked it. Pretty easy. Just call scrollToIndex in viewWillAppear method rather than viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to an item in a `UICollectionView` without animation you can use `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` and set `animated` to `NO`:

```
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO]
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, and have tried that. But that is not what I am looking for. I want to instantaneously go to the post detail x, and then load the previous and succeeding post details.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots? I don't really understand your navigation.

Comment: I added my mock up template in the question. The problem with using the option animated:NO is that each cell is a self-sizing cell, which is determined by the data response I get from a service call. So for example, if the user clicks on post title 100, the system tries to scroll instantaneously to post detail 100, while the information is still being downloaded. Hence the cells are resized once the download is complete and my final scroll to position is not post detail X, but some post detail x - k. To avoid this confusion, I want to directly load post detail X, and then fetch the other cells